# PDO PHP prepared and execute with UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, unix-timestamp

I'm having problems with my execution for inserting item into MYSQL

I currently have this code

```
$save = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tables(id,id2,datetime) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$save -> execute($id,$id2, "UNIX_TIMESTAMP()");
```

This gives me problems

```
PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 3 given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't use a function as param with execute.
Moreover, execute expects only one parameter : an array, you gave 3 parameters.

UNIX_TIMESTAMP() has to be written directly into the query and `$id1,$id2` have to be put in an array

```
$save = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tables(id,id2,datetime) VALUES(?,?,UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
$save -> execute(array($id,$id2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Matter not about function as param, the same problem I had
I just forgot to show data as array() items...
Either, you may use timestamp.

Instead of this:

```
$sec->execute($v,time(),$student_id);
```

One should be like this:

```
$sec->execute(array($v,time(),$student_id));
```